# Rounding the 3rd decimal down in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm looking to round some decimals to a maximum of 2 decimals, but always rounded down.

example:
I have `1.999` and want it rounded down to `1.99`
Likewise; `1.175` should be rounded down to `1.17`

So basically I'm looking for a FLOOR function but not on integers but on decimals. Does anyone know if a similar function exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

Use the TRUNC function with 2 decimals, eg: TRUNC (`1.999`, `2`) return `1.99`